# How do I create a computed column in an SQLite Table class definition in .Net Maui?

Tags: sqlite, maui

How do I create a computed column in an SQLite Table class definition in .Net Maui?

Here is the table...

```cs
[SQLite.Table("ItemHist")]
public class cl_ItemHist : TableData
{
    [NotNull, ForeignKey(typeof(cl_Stores))]
    public int Store_id { get; set; }
       
    [NotNull]
    public DateTime PurchDate { get; set; }
        
    [NotNull, ForeignKey(typeof(cl_Items))]
    public int Item_id { get; set; }
       
    [NotNull] 
    public float ItemQty { get; set; }
       
    [NotNull]
    public float TotalPrice { get; set; }
       
    [ForeignKey(typeof(cl_SaleCodes))]
    public int SaleCode_id { get; set; }

    [NotNull, ForeignKey(typeof(cl_Uom))]
    public int UnitPriceUom_id { get; set;}
        
    [NotNull, DefaultValue(0)]
    public int Purchased { get; set; }

    // References cl_Stores
    [OneToOne(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.CascadeRead)]
    public cl_Stores StoreName { get; set; }
        
    // References cl_Items
    [OneToOne(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.CascadeRead)]
    public cl_Items ItemName { get; set; }
        
    [OneToOne(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.CascadeRead)]
    public cl_Items ItemSize { get; set; }

    // References cl_SaleCodes
    [OneToOne(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.CascadeRead)]
    public cl_SaleCodes SaleCode { get; set; }

    // References cl_Uom from cl_Items
    [OneToOne(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.CascadeRead)]
    public cl_Uom Uom { get; set; }
}
```

The computed column I want to include contains three existing columns:

```
(TotalPrice / (ItemSize * ItemQty))
```

Comment: do you actually need the value to be stored in the db?  Or just a property that is dynamically calculated in memory?

Comment: I do not need it stored in the DB. I need a dynamic value that I can use as a binding in the xaml view the same as the other fields in the select.

Comment: just create a read-only property that returns the calculated value

Comment: My MVVM project has a XAML View that displays  many of the fields from the ItemHist table via binding to a Label Text property. The logic for reading the database is in the ViewModel. I do not know how or where to code a calculation using several of those fields that I can then bind to a Label Text in the View.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To exclude the computed property from sqlite, mark it `[Ignore]`.

```cs
[Ignore]
public float MyComputedColumn => . . .;
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/data-access/using-sqlite-orm#sqlite-attributes

However, you mention "dynamic". If you need display to be updated immediately, on any change of the three properties that affect this column, you’ll need additional code in the setters of those three properties. And class cl_itemHist will need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: I added the following lines to the cl_ItemHist class definition. ..                                       
        [Ignore]
        public float ComputedUnitPrice => ( TotalPrice) / (ItemQty * ItemSize.ItemSize);                    That worked. Thanks.